# passing parameters into generator functions

Tags: javascript

I'm learning generator functions in the codebase (redux sagas) and I'm seeing parameters passed in like

```
export function* someGenerator({ x, y = {} }) {
```

when I run it like

```
someGenerator('xyz', 'abc')
```

as with a regular function it comes out as undefined

I don't get the ({}) part or how I can pass a parameter into such a function.

thing is I'm trying to call a generator function within another one

Answer (score 2):

The function is using Default Object properties. It is doing two things:

- Destructuring the property `x` if the object with property `x` is provided to the function as first argument.
- Destructuring the property `y` of the given object. If there is not property `y` of the parameter then it will be assigned to empty object.

See the below examples:

```js
function someGenerator({ x, y = {} }) {
  console.log(x)
  console.log(y)
}

someGenerator({x:'xyz',y:'abc'})

someGenerator({x:'xyz'}) // 'y' will empty object.
```

Comment: Note that the function in this example isn't a generator; this isn't generator-specific syntax. Also note that JavaScript creates a new `{}` for `y` each time.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `generator`

default function parameters allows named parameters to be initialized with default value if no value or undefined is passed

```
export function* someGenerator({ x, y = {} }) {
```

when you run it like:

```
someGenerator('xyz', 'abc')
```

this is equivalent to:

```
let { x, y = {} } = 'xyz'
```

now:

```
x equal to undefined
y equal to {}
```

so you can use it like this:

```
someGenerator({ x: 'param1', y: 'param2' })
```